# Qt and OpenSSL on Android 9

Tags: android, qt, ssl, openssl, android-9.0-pie

I use OpenSSL in my Qt project for mobile App including Android.

I setup .so files and HTTPS works perfect until Android 9. I know that Android 9 version has enforced network security, particularly, by default it has disabled cleartext communications and allows only system CAs: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

I've faced an issue with HTTPS requests to custom HTTPS server with self-signed certificate on Android 9 - on earlier versions worked perfect.

I've made a test - set Network Security settings like in Android 9 defaults on Android 7.1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

- and this did not break HTTPS functionality. So, I suspect that Android 9 has not only Network Security default configuration change but something more, something that does not allow to work application-bundled openssl shared library.

Is this possible? How to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

In case of using Qt, Android Network Security configuration does not affect on communications and works transparently as for plain, so for TLS traffic.